# What is the correct rendering of ܟܕ in 1 Cor 11:4

Tags: grammar, definition

**1 Corinthians 11:4 [Khabouris Codex](http://dukhrana.com/peshitta/analyze_verse.php?verse=1Corinthians+11:4&font=Estrangelo+Edessa&size=150%&source=khabouris)**

> ܟܠ   ܓܒܪܐ   ܕܡܨܠܐ   ܐܘ   ܡܬܢܒܐ   ܟܕ   ܡܟܣܝ   ܪܫܗ   ܡܒܗܬ    ܪܫܗ

- (ܟܠ) all, every, whole, entirely
- (ܓܒܪܐ) man, husband, person
- (ܕܡܨܠܐ) incline toward, heed, pray
- (ܐܘ) O!, Oh!, or, else, rather than
- (ܡܬܢܒܐ) prophesy
- (ܟܕ) when, after, while, where
- (ܡܟܣܝ) cover, conceal, hide
- (ܪܫܗ) head, beginning, chiefs
- (ܡܒܗܬ) ashamed, shame
- (ܪܫܗ) head, beginning, chiefs

It appears that this word ܟܕ can mean (when, after, while, where)

**Build 1**

> Every man praying or prophesying when covering head shames head.

**Build 2**

> Every man praying or prophesying after covering head shames head.

**Build 3**

> Every man praying or prophesying while covering head shames head.

**Build 4**

> Every man praying or prophesying where covering head shames head.

### Question

Which build is most accurate considering Aramaic Language rules?

Comment: (-1) because something went haywire with your citation. Try bible.cc

Comment: @WoundedEgo. The Syriac looks fine on my screen. Maybe you do not have the right fonts?

Comment: @WoundedEgo Of note, Syriac (and Arabic) do not render correctly in old versions of Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"kad" followed by an active participle means "when" or "while", but not "after" or "where". So your (1) and (3) are correct, the others are not possible.